# Incorrect route returns blank page instead of custom error page

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.3, custom-error-pages

I made a custom error page for all errors in my system. I modified the `render` function in `app\Exceptions\Handler.php`:

```
if (Auth::user() != null && $exception->getMessage() != 'Unauthenticated.') { // user is logged in
    $var1 = Var1::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
    $var2 = Var2::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();

    if ($var1 != null) {
        return response()->view('errors.general', ['var1Id' => $var1->id]);
    } else if ($var2 != null) {
        return response()->view('errors.general', ['var2Id' => $var2->id]);
    } else {
        return response()->view('errors.general');
    }
} else { // user is not logged in
    return response()->view('errors.general');
}
```

When I enter a correct route in the browser, http://123.456.78.9/route/1/to/spelling, it goes to the appropriate page. But when I enter an incorrect one like, http://123.456.78.9/route/1/to/spelline, it just returns a blank page with no errors in the browser console.

I put a `dd('123')` in the first line of `render` function but it doesn't show. So it means, it doesn't go there. But where? Why a blank page?

Before this problem, I had a previous one and it returned an HTTP ERROR 500 in the browser instead of the custom error page that I made. I fixed it by modifying my `app/Http/Kernel.php`. I moved:

```
\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
```

from `'web'` to `protected $middleware`.

I reverted everything and I'm still getting the blank page. Do you have any idea about this?

EDIT 1:
My `routes/web.php` looks like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'route/{companyId}'], function () {
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'to'], function() {
            Route::get('spelling', 'MyController@spelling')->name('spelling.sample');
        });
    });
});
```

It works in SOME routes that are misspelled or incorrect. I am not sure what causes this. Please send help.

EDIT 2:
I just found out that when I enter incorrect routes (of a different controller), it's working fine. It's just that this specific controller is only having this problem.

Comment: oh wait! why did you use custom handler..? Laravel always read `/resources/view/<errcode>.blade.php` for error pages.. [read this docs regarding error page](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/errors#custom-http-error-pages).

Comment: Try without response(), e.g return view('errors.general', ['var1Id' => $var1->id]); and so on

Comment: What does your routes file look like?

Comment: @BagusTesa no i did not. I mage a `general.blade.php` for all errors.

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan no, the problem is not in the return statement. It doesn't go to the `render` function in the first place when I enter an incorrect route.

Comment: @patricus done editing my question